# Indeterminate form: $0^0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples

It is known that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$,
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}0^x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}x^0=1$. So sometimes $0^0$ is left undefined, sometimes defined as $1$.

A question then come to my mind:

Given $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are sequences$,\forall n\in\mathbb N,(s_n)\gt0\land(t_n)\gt0$, $\lim_n s_n=\lim_n t_n=0$.
**Given $a\in[0,1]$,When will $(s_n^{t_n})\to a$**? Even giving more example may help.

I have found some example,

1)$\forall n\in\mathbb N, s_n=t_n=\frac{1}{n},(s_n^{t_n})\to 1$

2)$\forall a\in(0,1), \forall n\in\mathbb N, s_n=a^n\land t_n=\frac{1}{n},(s_n^{t_n})\to a$

3)$\forall n\in\mathbb N, s_n=\frac{1}{n^n}\land t_n=\frac{1}{n},(s_n^{t_n})\to 0$

I think it sounds very 'easy' for $(s_n^{t_n})\to 1$, but are there similarity between the examples?

Or Can I even ask for:

**If $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=0, a\in\mathbb R$, when will $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)^{g(x)}=a$?**

Thanks.

Comment: $0^0$ is actually quite often defined as $1$ (not just "sometimes"). It's the natural value to give it in combinatorics, writing out things like Taylor series get needlessly messy if you don't (you have to put the constant term outside the general sum), and as far as I know it doesn't introduce any contradictions or similarily large problems the way assigning a value to $\frac00$ does. Of course, it doesn't fix the discontinuity of $x^y$ at the origin, but you can't win them all.

Comment: Yes, binomial theorem also make the convention $0^0=1$

Comment: @Arthur I agree, but some people insist that there is no reason to define it that way. Another good reason to do it is that the binomial theorem can be formulated without restricting to numbers different from $0$.

Comment: The very reason for which $({\to}0)^{{\to}0}$ is deemed as an indeterminate form is that the limit cannot be predicted by just *looking* at the two sequence $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$, but instead depends on their reciprocal interaction when forming $s_n^{t_n}$. Your question is much similar to asking the ultimate question on life, universe and everything.

Comment: I assume you want an answer besides what one gets by logarithmically converting to a $0 \cdot \infty$ indeterminate form? Anyway, some of the examples [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2077549-7075099-600126/seq2.pdf) might be of interest. Also, given any nonempty closed subset $E$ of $[0,\infty],$ I'm pretty sure there exist functions $f$ and $g$ (continuous, if $E$ is connected) such that the set of subsequence limit points of $f^g$ as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$ is equal to $E,$ and so a more general question is to characterize such functions for a specified set $E.$

Comment: @ Dave L. Renfro Why? Can you give an reference to book?

Comment: $x\to0^+$ is irrelevant. What matters is $f(x)\to0^+,g(x)\to0$ whatever the limit of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we need $f(x)\to 0^+$ for the expression to be well defined, then

$$f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\log(f(x))}\to a>0$$

since all depends upon

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)\log(f(x))$$

For the case $a=+\infty$ let consider

- $f(x)=x \to 0$
- $g(x)=-|\log x|^{-\frac12}\to0$

indeed since $x\to 0^+$

$$g(x)\log(f(x))=-|\log x|^{-\frac12}\log x=-\frac{\log x}{|\log x|^\frac12}=\frac{|\log x|}{|\log x|^\frac12}=|\log x|^\frac12\to +\infty$$

Comment: In the last sentence, why $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$?

Comment: @TonyMa ops sorry just a typo on exponent! Thanks for the pointing out

Comment: ,Can you prove the example converges to $+\infty$? Thx

Comment: @TonyMa I've just added some details